# Implementing SSR with React and ASP.NET core 5 with Razor pages

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, razor

I am researching the best way to Implementing React with Razor pages in ASP.NET core with Razor pages.  I haven't really been able to find anything that applies to .NET 6 only .NET 5 and older.  The initial plan was to use something like InertiaJs, I was able to find a NuGet package for that unfortunately they stopped support after .NET 5. I started looking for other SSR implementations and found some packages that are out of date.

I am just putting this out here to see if anyone knows anything or has any leads on this. If I find anything I will make sure to put it in the comments.

Comment: Why do you want to render React within Razor? Having gone through this experience in past, I suggest picking one and sticking to it.

Comment: [I forked the code some time ago](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing). Note that `SpaPrerenderingOptions.SupplyData` is now replaced with `AddSpaPrerenderingService<>` and `ISpaPrerenderingService.OnSupplyData`...